# Reading Json Data

Tags: json

I want to extract the WKT data (only Polygon) from below json below but can't read it. Can someone please help I should get only
`POLYGON ((50643441 47943921, 01030605 11233944, 37149703 57863113, 76470172 87135344, 50643441 47943921))` data like this

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "resultCode":0,
      "resultInfo":null,
      "updateIniSearchForm":null,
      "subSearchEntry":null,
      "data":"{\"parishCode\":null,\"shapes\":[{\"identifier\":\"2769940\",\"displayTitle\":null,\"layerName\":null,\"wkt\":\"POLYGON ((50643441 47943921, 01030605 11233944, 37149703 57863113, 76470172 87135344, 50643441 47943921))\"}],\"bbox\":\"1111, 2222, 333, 2407664\",\"type\":\"Address\",\"srid\":3456}",
      "surveyLabelTables":null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working

Have to parse the string again

```
var wktData = JSON.parse(body.result.data);
       var polygonData = wktData.shapes[0].wkt;
```